# How do I create another element after looping through a set number of elements?

Tags: python, list

I'm adding the length of an input list to a parameter with string formatting:

```
input_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
freq_list = "freq=[{}]".format(len(input_list))
print(freq_list)
```

When I try to print the string, it shows `'freq=[13]'`, which shows that the length of the `input_list` is 13, which is fine by itself. But what if I want a new element created every 10 elements as it loops through the data list?

In this, with a length of 13, how can I get `'freq=[10, 3]'` instead of `'freq=[13]'`?

Some more examples:

- If the length is 11: `'freq=[10, 1]'`
- If the length is 24: `'freq=[10, 10, 4]'`

Comment: I was gonna return the list with a bunch of stats inside it but didn't want to include a whole function in here. My bad if it's inconvenient.

Comment: Note that you didn't have a list of tuples (before my edit). `(0)` is just `0`, grouped. You need *commas* to make tuples, so `(0,)` would be a tuple with one element. It doesn't matter for your question here what's in the input list however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop here, you can use simple arithmetic to calculate how many 10s there are in the length. You want to divide the length by 10 (using the [`//` floor division operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)) to get the number of tens, and use the [`%` modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) to get the remainder of the division:

```
length = len(input_list)
tens, remainder = length // 10, length % 10
freq_list = "freq={}".format([10] * tens + ([remainder] if remainder else []))
```

Note that I formatted the *whole list* constructed from separate `[10]` and `[remainder]` components. The representation of a list object with integers fits your specified output exactly, with a space after each comma:

```
>>> length = 11
>>> tens, remainder = length // 10, length % 10
>>> "freq={}".format([10] * tens + ([remainder] if remainder else []))
'freq=[10, 1]'
>>> length = 24
>>> tens, remainder = length // 10, length % 10
>>> "freq={}".format([10] * tens + ([remainder] if remainder else []))
'freq=[10, 10, 4]'
```

The remainder portion is dropped and you only get `10` values if the length is a multiple of 10:

```
>>> length = 20
>>> tens, remainder = length // 10, length % 10
>>> "freq={}".format([10] * tens + ([remainder] if remainder else []))
'freq=[10, 10]'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `//` (integer division operator, to get the number of tens in the length), `%` (modulo operator, to get the remainder), and list multiplication:

```
input_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

n = len(input_list)

freq_list = "freq=[{}]".format(','.join(['10'] * (n // 10) + [str(n % 10)]))

print(freq_list)
```

Output:

```
'freq=[10,3]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to generate a list of `10`'s depending on the size of the input, then join it to a string using `', '` separator.

The if the length is not a multiple of 10, then use the modulus operator to find the remaining element count and add it to the string generated in the earlier step.

```
input_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
             10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
             20, 21, 23, 24] 

item_list = ', '.join(['10' for i in range(len(input_list) // 10)])
last_item = ', ' + str(len(input_list) % 10) if  len(input_list) % 10 > 0 else ''
freq_list = "freq=[{}]".format(item_list + last_item)
print(freq_list)
```

Output:

```
'freq=[10, 10, 5]'
```

Comment: You really don't need to use a list comprehension here. `['10'] * <number of repetitions>` would do just fine. Don't try to cram everything into a single line, using a few variables to store the length and the output of the calculations makes the code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry about the bad styling, I fixed it. I did not edit out the list comprehension part as the technique of using `*` is already there in another answer :)

Comment: You'd be much better off building an `item_list` *without* joining, and then appending `last_item` to that if `len(tuple_list) % 10 > 0` is true, and only *then* use a `str.join()` on the whole list. Note how much easier it would be to write that condition if there was a `remainder` variable, however.